# Regression analysis on MICE R

Tags: r, regression, imputation, r-mice

I recently updated the MICE package and some code I had before broke...
I don't use MICE very much so would be extremely grateful for suggestions on a fix

```
imputed_scabies_model <- with(coded_imputed_scabies,glm(impetigo_active~factor(scabies_infestation)+factor(gender)+factor(agegroups), family = binomial()))
```

> Fit model to the imputed dataset

```
imputed_scabies_model_summary <- (summary(pool(imputed_scabies_model)))
```

> Get summary statistics

```
imputed_scabies_model_OR <-exp(cbind(imputed_scabies_model_summary[,"est"],imputed_scabies_model_summary[,"lo 95"],imputed_scabies_model_summary[,"hi 95"]))
```

> Exponentiate the Estimate, the lower and higher 95% CI to get an OR and 95%CI

```
imputed_scabies_model_summary <- (cbind(imputed_scabies_model_OR,imputed_scabies_model_summary))
```

> Bring everything together -  so I'd have a table with the OR, its 95% CI, and then the raw output of the model too.

I think the issue is that the output of

```
imputed_scabies_model <- with(coded_imputed_scabies,glm(impetigo_active~factor(scabies_infestation)+factor(gender)+factor(agegroups), family = binomial()))
imputed_scabies_model_summary <- (summary(pool(imputed_scabies_model)))
```

This used to give the estimate, lower and upper bounds of the 95% CI as separate columns.
Estimate still comes out (now called estimate rather than "est" - so easy to fix that bit of code) but now the summary just seems to have the SE rather than the CI bounds.

[![output of imputed_scabies_model_summary <- (summary(pool(imputed_scabies_model)))
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmUmH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmUmH.png)

So I guess I need to exponentiate and then generate the CIs manually - but was wondering if people who use MICE more frequently might be able to provide some guidance.

I hope my query is clear. I can provide a dataset if helpful.

Comment: See the help page `?mice:::summary.mipo`: The summary method has arguments `conf.int` (FALSE by default) and `exponentiate`, so you just need to add those arguments to your `summary()` call I think.

Comment: Perfect - thank you so much!